# Como aumentar a quantidade de casas decimais depois da vírgula?

Tags: javafx, valor-monetário

Como eu posso fazer o campo exibir 0,0000 por exemplo ? Por padrão ele só seta 2 casas, não estou conseguindo aumentar.

Exemplo:

```java
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class CampoMonetario extends TextField {

    public CampoMonetario() {
        setValor("0,00");
        //setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red;");

        lengthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                String value = getText();
                value = value.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
                value = value.replaceAll("([0-9]{1})([0-9]{14})$", "$1.$2");
                value = value.replaceAll("([0-9]{1})([0-9]{11})$", "$1.$2");
                value = value.replaceAll("([0-9]{1})([0-9]{8})$", "$1.$2");
                value = value.replaceAll("([0-9]{1})([0-9]{5})$", "$1.$2");
                value = value.replaceAll("([0-9]{1})([0-9]{2})$", "$1,$2");
                setText(value);

                textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observableValue, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                        if (newValue.length() > 16) {
                            setText(oldValue);
                        }
                        if (newValue.length() > 4) {
                            if (newValue.substring(0, 1).contains("0")) {
                                setText(newValue.substring(0, 1).replace("0", "") + getText().substring(1, getText().length()));
                            } else if (newValue.substring(0, 2).contains("0.")) {
                                setText(newValue.substring(0, 1).replace("0", "") + getText().substring(1, getText().length()));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observableValue, Boolean out, Boolean in) {


                if ((new BigDecimal(getValor() + "0")).compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) <= 0 && in) {
                    setText("");
                } else if (getText().equals("") && out) {
                    setText("0,00");
                }
                final int length = (getText().length());
                if (length > 0 && length < 4) {
                    setText(getText() + "00");
                    lengthProperty();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public void setValor(Object valor) {
        if (!(valor + "").contains("nul")) {
            setText(String.valueOf(valor).replace(".", ",").replace("", ""));
            requestFocus();
        } else {
            setText("0,00");
        }
    }

    public BigDecimal getValor() {
        return ((!getText().isEmpty()) ? new BigDecimal(getText().replace(".", "").replace(",", ".")) : BigDecimal.ZERO.setScale(2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Mas se a proposta do seu campo é ser um campo monetário duas casa é suficiente pois o limite de centavos é 99. Ou não?

Answer (score -1):

Só aumentar o Scale do bigdecimal, como abaixo, por exemplo passando de um double pra um scale 12.

```
double d = ...
BigDecimal db = new BigDecimal(d).setScale(12, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

Comment: onde eu vou aplicar esse db ?